# Kendo TreeView: How to set Intermediate state Programmatically

Tags: angularjs, kendo-ui, kendo-treeview

I am trying to use Kendo TreeView with other controls. Each of the leaf node on tree opens a detail pane. When I select all the elements from detail pane, I set the state of that node as Checked

```
myTree.dataItem(node).set("checked", true);
```

and when all the items are un-selected, I set the state of node as unchecked.

```
myTree.dataItem(node).set("checked", false);
```

but if some of the items are selected, I want to show the state of node as Intermediate

how can I do that. I cant find anything in the documentation that can help me. The closest thing I found is

```
myTree.updateIndeterminate()
```

however, it is not doing the job. Apparently, it sets the state based on the state of child nodes. but in my case, there are no child nodes. I am dealing with leaf nodes here. Can I set the state of a leaf node as Intermediate ? if yes, how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couldn't find any help on this. 
Ended up using the following approach

I am now finding the checkbox associated with that particular node and setting it's `indeterminate` value using jQuery.

```
function SetTreeNodeIndeterminate(nodeId, set) {
  var uid = $("#" + nodeId).parents('li').attr('data-uid');
  var node = myTree.findByUid(uid);
  if (node.length == 0) return;
  var checkBox = $("#_" + uid);
  if (checkBox.length == 0) return;
  checkBox.prop('indeterminate', set);
  updateParentNodeState(node);
}
```

the following line makes sure that all the parents of a node are also marked as indeterminate

```
function updateParentNodeState(node) {
  myTree.updateIndeterminate(node);
  let parentNode = myTree.parent(node);
  if (parentNode.length > 0)
    updateParentNodeState(parentNode);
}
```